# Control external peripheral using android app

Tags: android, arduino, raspberry-pi, android-hardware, ioio

I had IOIO board and went through DIY Samples, like controlling LED, DC motor, Servo motor.. it was very interesting, and I want to design a toy remote car which should be controlled by an android app, There are many android boards available like Hackberry a10, Arduino, Raspberry Pi..etc,  as I'm a newbie to hardware domain, I do not know much about boards. So kindly update me on Which one is the best and versatile?, I'm going to use Android studio for the development, not the processing. Is there any other protocols available for transmitting the signals other than BT, IR, and Wi-fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Arduino, which provides a wide variety of hardware to connect with. Please go through [arduino store](https://store.arduino.cc/) . There are many samples available for Arduino. Please refer [this](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino) may help you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Best is a tough question, but if you are a hardware newbie, the easiest system to get started with is probably the [LittleBits](http://littlebits.cc/) Cloud pack. Once you've prototyped what you need, you can replace it with something more practical in terms of form factor.